# Disassociate Game Center account from device without access to device

Tags: ios, password, game-center, clash-of-clans

I play the game Clash of Clans on my iPad, and for a while I allowed a friend to use my Game Center account. Now I need it back but he won't let me play it. He changes the layout and ruins it and everything. I changed the password but he can still play the game since my base is now attached to his iPad.

Is there anything I can do to dissociate his device with my Game Center ID to prevent him from continuing to play the game from my user?

Comment: This seems like a social problem more than a technical problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about Apple related products or services.

Comment: I would say that "anything I can do to dissociate his device with my Game Center ID" is a sensible, technical, and Apple related - I just don't know how to help.

Comment: @Joe This was edited in to the question after the close vote.